# idHTTP.Post Error HTTP/1.1 401

Tags: json, delphi

I am trying to access the idHTTP Delphi in a json server without success. I've tried all the alternatives and always got the same error: "HTTP / 1.1 401 Unauthorized".

JSON format for testing:

> {"http":{"method":"POST","header":"access_token:55b3ce85b47629eeee778c0f0c9be450f1b1bc84cc377975f2d3d0d3808a4636", "content":"name=TEST&email=teste@uol.com&phone=1147001211&mobilePhone=11992329909&address=Rua+Jose+Ricardo &addressNumber=55&province=Test&notificationDisabled=True&city=Sao+Paulo&state=SP&country=Brasil&postalCode=05567210 &cpfCnpj=11111111111&personType=FISICA"}}

Url for testing:

> http://homolog.asaas.com/api/v2/customers

Procedure for testing:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 sResponse: string;
 EnvStr : TStringList;
begin
 EnvStr := TStringList.Create;
 EnvStr.AddStrings(Memo.Lines);
 try
  idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  idHTTP.Request.Method:='POST';
  idHTTP.Request.AcceptCharSet := 'utf-8';
  try
   sResponse := idHTTP.Post(EditURL.Text,EnvStr);
  except
   on E: Exception do
    ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
  end;
 finally
  MemoRet.Lines.Clear;
  MemoRet.Lines.add(sResponse);
 end;
end;
```

The same format sent in PHP works perfectly, but with idHTTP returns the error: "HTTP / 1.1 401 Unauthorized".

PHP works perfectly

```
<?php
 $api_url = "http://homolog.asaas.com/api/v2";   
 $api_key = "55b3ce85b47629eeee778c0f0c9be450f1b1bc84cc377975f2d3d0d3808a4636";
 $url_cus = $api_url."/customers";
 $param = array(
'name' => utf8_encode('Test'),
'email' => 'test@uol.com.br',
'phone' => '1147001211',
'mobilePhone' => '11992329909',
'address' => utf8_encode('Rua Jose Ricardo'),
'addressNumber' => '55',
'province' => 'Test',
'notificationDisabled' => 'True',
'city' => 'Sao Paulo',
'state' =>'SP',
'country' => 'Brasil',
'postalCode' => '05567210',
'cpfCnpj' => '11111111111',
'personType' => 'FISICA'
  );
 $req = http_build_query($param);
 $ctx = stream_context_create(
 array(
       "http" => array(
       "method" => "POST",
       "header" => "access_token: $api_key",
       "content" => $req
        )
      )
     );

 $res = file_get_contents($url_cus, true, $ctx);

 //PHP Object
 $obj = json_decode($res);

 //get id of register 
 $id=utf8_decode("$obj->id");

 // return result
 // return $id;

?>
```

Comment: You can use a HTTP proxy (Fiddler2 for example) to record the PHP POST request and the Delphi POST request and then use a diff tool to compare the requests to find the differences

Comment: Or you can use Wireshark, since the URL is HTTP and not HTTPS. Any packet sniffer will work in this case.

Comment: +1 for analysing the difference between the PHP and the Delphi requests.  Clearly your Delphi code is not sending the request in exactly the same manner as the working PHP solution since if it were you would not get this result.  Your working PHP example is your best reference (and posting that PHP code in the question for comparison might help others identify your problem if you are unable to do so).

Comment: I added the example php that works perfectly. I'm using Fiddler (I'm layman) and still could not find the bug. If you can help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to access the idHTTP Delphi in a json server without success.

You are not posting the JSON data correctly.  You cannot use a `TStringList`, as that version of `TIdHTTP.Post()` is meant for posting HTML webforms, which you are not posting.  You need to post the JSON data using a `TStream` instead, eg:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
 sResponse: string;
 EnvStr : TStringStream;
begin
 EnvStr := TStringStream.Create(Memo.Text, TEncoding.UTF8);
 try
  idHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  try
   sResponse := idHTTP.Post(EditURL.Text, EnvStr);
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
  end;
finally
  EnvStr.Free;
  MemoRet.Text := sResponse;
end;
```

> I've tried all the alternatives and always got the same error: "HTTP / 1.1 401 Unauthorized".

Usually that means the server is asking for authentication credentials, which you are not providing.  However, in this situation, there is no `WWW-Authenticate` header present in the server's response to provide challenge information, which is in clear violation of the HTTP protocol spec.

> The same format sent in PHP works perfectly

Then you need to use a packet sniffer, such as Wireshark, to capture the HTTP requests being generated by PHP and `TIdHTTP` and then compare them for any differences that you can then code into `TIdHTTP` as needed.

---

**Update**: based on your PHP code, I can now see that your Delphi code is trying to `POST` a JSON formatted string, but your PHP code is instead `POST`ing an HTML webform containing `name=value` pairs in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.  There is no JSON involved in the request at all.  Only the response is using JSON.

Looking back at it now, the PHP code is acting on simply arrays, not on real JSON.  I think you got confused between the two, because the representation of the array data looks like JSON but it is actually not.  If you read the PHP documentation, [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) simply returns a string representing an HTTP url query string, and then [`stream_context_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) is creating a stream based on an array of [HTTP context options](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php), where the query string is set as the `content` option, and then [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) is sending a request based on those options - in this case an HTTP `POST` request with an `access_token` header and the query string as the message body.  Since no `Content-Type` header is being specified, it defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

To `POST` an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request with `TIdHTTP`, you were actually on the right track by using a `TStringList` with `TIdHTTP.Post()`, but you were populating the `TStringList` with the wrong kind of data, and you were not sending the `access_token` header containing your authentication credentials.

The following Delphi code works when I test it:

```
procedure TForm4.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sResponse: string;
  EnvStr : TStringList;
begin
  EnvStr := TStringList.Create;
  try
    EnvStr.Add('name=TEST');
    EnvStr.Add('email=teste@uol.com');
    EnvStr.Add('phone=1147001211');
    EnvStr.Add('mobilePhone=11992329909');
    EnvStr.Add('address=Rua Jose Ricardo ');
    EnvStr.Add('addressNumber=55');
    EnvStr.Add('province=Test');
    EnvStr.Add('notificationDisabled=True');
    EnvStr.Add('city=Sao Paulo');
    EnvStr.Add('state=SP');
    EnvStr.Add('country=Brasil');
    EnvStr.Add('postalCode=05567210 ');
    EnvStr.Add('cpfCnpj=11111111111');
    EnvStr.Add('personType=FISICA');

    Http.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['access_token'] := '55b3ce85b47629eeee778c0f0c9be450f1b1bc84cc377975f2d3d0d3808a4636';
    try
      sResponse := idHTTP.Post(EditURL.Text, EnvStr);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage('Error on request: '#13#10 + e.Message);
    end;
  finally
    EnvStr.Free;
    MemoRet.Text := sResponse;
  end;
end;
```

Response received:

> {"object":"customer","id":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","name":"TEST","email":"teste@uol.com","company":null,"phone":"1147001211","mobilePhone":"11992329909","address":"Rua Jose Ricardo","addressNumber":"55","complement":null,"province":"Test","postalCode":"05567210","cpfCnpj":"11111111111","personType":"FISICA","deleted":false,"notificationDisabled":true,"city":null,"state":"null","country":"Brasil","foreignCustomer":false,"subscriptions":{"object":"list","hasMore":false,"limit":100,"offset":0,"data":[]},"payments":{"object":"list","hasMore":false,"limit":100,"offset":0,"data":[]},"notifications":{"object":"list","hasMore":false,"limit":100,"offset":0,"data":[{"object":"notification","id":"not_oZV4SlDvdjHf","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":true,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_RECEIVED","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_xNHXDZb4QHqP","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":true,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_OVERDUE","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_yt4BTyQsaRM1","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":false,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_DUEDATE_WARNING","scheduleOffset":10,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_LX1vanmAsBy9","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":false,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_DUEDATE_WARNING","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_AyYUHDExa5Zk","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":false,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_CREATED","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_b6NUt9qYZrM2","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":false,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"PAYMENT_UPDATED","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false},{"object":"notification","id":"not_Z4e4SHdXsJaA","customer":"cus_B5HmHFQSMZKD","enabled":true,"emailEnabledForProvider":false,"smsEnabledForProvider":false,"emailEnabledForCustomer":true,"smsEnabledForCustomer":true,"event":"SEND_LINHA_DIGITAVEL","scheduleOffset":0,"deleted":false}]}}

Comment: It's beyond the scope of the question since the server implementation is not up for debate/modification, but as an observation on RESTful API's and the apparent behaviour in this case ... "Not authorized" would be (*should* be) a **403** (*I know who you are and you are not authorized to do that*).  Seems to me in this case the server should be returning a flat out **400 Bad Request**.  But then too many RESTful API's just do whatever the hell they like when it comes to responses and HTTP standards be damned.

Comment: Agreed. In fact, the HTTP spec clearly states that 401 **MUST** include a `WWW-Authenticate` header, but this server is not doing that.

Comment: I added the example php that works perfectly. I'm using Fiddler (I'm layman) and still could not find the bug. If you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Now that we can see your PHP code, your Delphi code is wrong.  I have updated my answer.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, I also solved the problem with the help of Wireshark, but its solution is more elegant, thank you!